# How can I create a range from the input of a datatable c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Okay so I have a datatable to input into a datagridview.

Inside the datatable we have:

```
dt.rows.add(row.DocName, row.DocDate, row.ID);
```

etc etc.

I am now wondering if there is anyway to collaborate all of the inputs i.e.

```
dt.rows.add(row.Data);
```

This would also be useful in the instance where a new datatable is created. As I am comparing two sets of data to find unique entries. The entries then stripped out and finally added to a new datatable and added to a datagridview.

Comment: You can use `DataTable.ImportRow`

Answer (score 0):

If the items are in the same order as the row you are adding. You could do this:

```
dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```

The ItemArray contains an array of the items